# JOOMLA- Show articles under a category in two columns with read more option

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

In a joomla application i have a services listing page.Under Services category several articles are added.Now on clicking the services button i want to display latest 8 articles in two column layout with about 200 chars and a read more button linked to each to display whole article? I implemented but Now am able to list the articles in single layout using blog category listing property but i cannot able to do two column display..Any help appreciated

Comment: which version of joomla you are using ....???

Comment: @Pramod Kumar Sharma joomla2.5

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you should have to give to no of columns in Blog layout option while creating the menu.It will divide the page into the no of columns you define in the options and then change the Articles Options.